# Using vst live and sound library advices

Tags: keyboard, daw, rock-n-roll, vst, live

I'm an amateur keyboard musician in a band mainly playing rock and metal songs, using a korg x50. This keyboard is great for its relatively small size and weight, but I'm lacking a bit of more realistic sounds (especially for instruments like pianos, guitars, organs). I recently went into vsts using my personal home computer, and I'm pretty sure there is something to do with this.

Here are my questions :

- I would like to use vst live with my band, so I have a laptop, what's necessary to connect everything together, but I'm not sure what kind of vst host is more suited for live performance? I was thinking of getting cubase as I can use it for other stuff, but is this adapted for live using of vst? Any suggestion?
- do you have recommendations for great (not too expansive) vsts libraries for pianos? Guitars (classic and electric with overdrive and stuff)? Hammond organs?
- are there great good value vst package you recommend?
- what do you use to sort your vsts, and how do you manage to switch from one to another during live (maybe related to first question)?

Thanks a lot,
Cheers
Jérémy

Comment: Hello Jeremy, questions about product recommendations are considered OT on this site.

Comment: Welcome! You can check out [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There are probably some related questions that would be on-topic here, if they focused more on "how do I ___" than "what tool should I use to ___."

Comment: Two big issues with laptops with respect to live performance is 1) latency-related crackle and skipping (real time audio does not like sharing CPU time with disk operations and background services); 2) ground loops. running off battery is an easy way to avoid ground loop noise, but then the battery needs to be robust. Don't just get some stuff and then jump on stage